# Changing Revit BuiltInParameter when on Design Option

Tags: c#, parameters, revit-api

In Revit, when changing a `BuiltInParameter` which is on a Design Option, it gets an error that it is read-only.

The line of code is:
`floor.get_Parameter(BuiltInParameter.FLOOR_HEIGHTABOVELEVEL_PARAM).Set(currentStoopHeigth - joist9Height)`

there is a `isReadOnly`, but I do not know how to add it.

I do not know how to add `isReadOnly` to the line of code.  I need to grab this parameter whether on Design Option or not, and change it.

Comment: How do you achieve what you need manually in the end user interface? The same approach will generally also work programmatically in the API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are able to edit a parameter in Revit, then you should be able to edit it from the API. The `Parameter.IsReadOnly` is intended to let you know whether or not a parameter is editable for a given element. This should help prevent errors where you try to set the value of a parameter that cannot be edited.

Note that you cannot control `Parameter.IsReadOnly` property from the API since it is only a `get` property.

Here is a way to check if a parameter is read only:

```cs
var floorHeightAboveLevelParam = floor.get_Parameter(BuiltInParameter.FLOOR_HEIGHTABOVELEVEL_PARAM);

if (floorHeightAboveLevelParam != null && !floorHeightAboveLevelParam.IsReadOnly)
{
   floorHeightAboveLevelParam.Set(currentStoopHeigth - joist9Height);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this allowed me to skip over the floors that have the height parameter as read-only.  The custom menus I'm making need to work on 100+ houses.  I still haven't figured out why this house has it as read-only and the others are fine.

Comment: I found out why the Height Above Level is greyed out or read-only.  The slope arrow has a Head and Tail level of FIRST FLR, instead of "Default".